# modify image in c++ using opencv

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

i want to modify image in c++ using opencv and this is my code

```
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <highgui.h>  
 using namespace std;
 int main(int* argc ,char* argv[]){  
 IplImage* image =cvLoadImage ("D://s1//1.pgm",0);
 //cvShowImage( "Source",image);
 int h=image->height;
 int w=image->width;
 CvScalar pix;
 IplImage* img2 = cvCreateImage( cvSize(h,w), 8, 1 );
 CvMat* mat1  = cvCreateMat(h,w,CV_32FC1);
 CvMat* mat2  = cvCreateMat(h,w,CV_32FC1);
 cvConvert(image,mat1);
 for(int i=0;i<h;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<w;j++){
    if(i==j){
    pix =1;
    cvSet2D(mat2,i,j,pix.val[0]);}
    else{
    pix = cvGet2D( mat1,i,j);
    cvSet2D(mat2,i,j,pix.val[0]); }  
    }      
 }
 cvConvert(mat2,img2 );
 cvShowImage( "image",img2);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 return 0;}
```

but it not worked,I need your help and your advice,please Join us your perspectives.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? We need a clue... Can you give us the error code or something like that?

Comment: What kind of modification are you trying to do?

Comment: i would like modified in some pixel in image

Comment: error: 'cvSet2D' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'double' to 'CvScalar'

Comment: Please be more specific in your question and problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <highgui.h>  
 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc ,char** argv[]){  
 CvScalar pix;
 IplImage* img2 = cvCreateImage( cvSize(500,500), 32,3 );
 for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
    pix = cvGet2D( img2,i,j);
    pix.val[0]=rand()%150;
    pix.val[1]=rand()%150;
    pix.val[2]=rand()%150;
    cvSet2D(img2,i,j,pix); }     
 cvShowImage( "image",img2);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

cvSet2D(mat2,i,j,pix.val[0]);

is syntactically incorrect. It should be

cvSet2D(mat2,i,j,pix);

If you want to modify the RGB values of pix, that has to be done before this line.

for an arbitrary example,

pix.val[0]=pix.val[0]/2;

If you tell us what exactly the modification is, the question will be easier to answer.

Comment: thank you very much for interestingly answer,but this also is not worked with me ,i want to modify in some pixels in grayscale image

Comment: What is the modification you want to do? Also, you are doing too many conversions if you just want to modify pixels. Your could use IplImage without converting to cvMat, for this purpose.